# Linux kernel knowledge about physical memory

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I understand that for every process virtual addresses are mapped to physical pages.The corresponding physical page number for a given virtual page number would be available in page table entry.

But i am curious to know how this mapping is done by kernel. How does kernel knows which physical page is free before allocating that page to a virtual page number. Does it keeps track of all the available empty pages in physical memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the kernel keeps a data structure describing the current status of all the physical pages that are available - an array of [`struct page`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12/include/linux/mm_types.h#L41) entries, one for each physical page.

Comment: So it keeps track of each page is either free or used. am i right??  if i am right,how does kernel finds out the available free pages in that array.?  does it traverse through each index and check whether it is free or already mapped?  or does it maintains a separate data structure which holds only the unallocated pages?

Comment: @user1762571: References to free pages are kept in a data structure - a linear search each time a free page was required would be highly inefficient.  The [Buddy Allocator](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html) is used for physical page allocation.